# Is there a way to get the last cleared/deselect date on bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) to multi-select dates (multidate: true). Is there a way to get the last cleared/deselected date?

I want to fire a callback function when the user clear/deselect a date and I want to pass the deselected date to the function. How can I do this?

I have implemented it like this so far: https://jsfiddle.net/nipunadodan/9dqu3gb6/9

But `clearDate` doesn't seems to fire up when deselecting a date.

```js
function standardDate(date) {
  const dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  const mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0
  const yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  return yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
}

$('#bd-picker').datepicker({
  multidate: true,
  weekStart: 1,
  maxViewMode: 2,
  clearBtn: false,
  format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
  autoclose: false,
  todayHighlight: true,
});

$('#bd-picker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
  const selectedDates = $('#bd-picker').datepicker('getDate');
  console.log('last selected date: '+standardDate(selectedDates));
});

$('#bd-picker').datepicker().on('clearDate', function (e) {
  const cleared = $('#bd-picker').datepicker('getDate')
  console.log(e.date);
  console.log('cleared date: '+standardDate(cleared));
});
```

Comment: Store the `event.dates` array then query for what was removed

Comment: @charlietfl You mean it as in comparing the new array with the last array?

I have been thinking of it as a last resort. Docs don't have anything regarding deselected dates so I wanted to see if there's anything straightforward that I'm missing here.

Comment: If such functionality is built in it doesn't appear to be documented which is why I suggested comparing before/after arrays